# Setting up Windows SDK in VS2012 Windows7

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-studio-2012, directx-11

I'm trying to set up Windows SDK for DirectX11 but having a bit of trouble.
I'm on Windows7 with Visual Studio 2012.

The error I'm getting is:

```
1>TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "fxc.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So I assume it isn't locating the SDK correctly (I think it's an HLSL error).
So far in my project directories I have:

```
Include directories: $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)
Library directories: $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86)
Library WinRT directories: $(WindowsSDK_MetadataPath)
```

I've checked where these macros go, and they go to the right place:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\etc...
```

which is where I installed it, however the error I wrote above is still showing up.

I'm stumped as to what to do next, could anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is located in C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\fxc.exe, first check if it is there.

The VS setting that matters is Project + Properties, VC++ Directories, Executable Directories.  It normally includes `$(WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86)` so should never have a problem locating the file.

Comment: Thanks, my executable directories wasn't inherited from defaults! Is there a way to get rid of the DirectX10 directories from the defaults? Both SDKs are inheriting and pulling up redefinition warnings which is getting a bit frustrating. 
Thanks again